# How do I use a Java JSONArray with D3 and Dimple, passed using Spring MVC? I'm getting a 404 error

Tags: json, d3.js, dimple.js

Using Spring MVC, I have a JSONArray in my controller, which I pass to my view using view.addObject like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/graphWeek")
public ModelAndView getGraphWeek(){
    JSONArray tweetsForWeek = getGraphWeekData();
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("graphWeek");
    mv.addObject("tweetsForWeek", tweetsForWeek);
    return mv;
}
```

In my jsp view, I have this:

```
var svg = dimple.newSvg("#bar", 800, 500);
var src= ${tweetsForWeek};
console.log(src);

d3.json(src, function (error, data) {
  var barChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
  barChart.addCategoryAxis("x", ["Day", "Topic"]);
  barChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Tweets");
  barChart.addSeries("Topic", dimple.plot.bar);
  barChart.addLegend(100, 10, 510, 20, "right");
  barChart.width = 600;
  barChart.height = 400;
  barChart.draw();
});
```

I added a console.log(src) call to make sure the array was being received by the view and it is. But my graph doesn't display and it gives me an error. This is the result of loading my view, showing the console log and error in firebug:

[image]

So you can see in the console that the array is being received by the view but it is not being handled correctly by d3, does anyone know what could be causing this error? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: The first argument to `d3.json` should be a URL, not an array.

Comment: Oh, I think I understand.  If `src` is the array data, why are you calling `d3.json`?  That's to make a call to the server and retreive json.  You already have your object.

Comment: Ah, you're right, I removed d3.json and just passed the array to dimple. Would you like to add your solution as an answer and I'll accept it? Thanks by the way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `d3.json` here.   You have your data already.

```
var svg = dimple.newSvg("#bar", 800, 500);
var src= ${tweetsForWeek};
console.log(src);

var barChart = new dimple.chart(svg, src); //<-- you have your data already
barChart.addCategoryAxis("x", ["Day", "Topic"]);
barChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Tweets");
barChart.addSeries("Topic", dimple.plot.bar);
barChart.addLegend(100, 10, 510, 20, "right");
barChart.width = 600;
barChart.height = 400;
barChart.draw();
```

The alternative here is to, of course, forget using the JSP templating to load your array and do it via JSON:

```
d3.json("/graphWeek", function (error, data) {
    var svg = dimple.newSvg("#bar", 800, 500);
    var barChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
    barChart.addCategoryAxis("x", ["Day", "Topic"]);
    barChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Tweets");
    barChart.addSeries("Topic", dimple.plot.bar);
    barChart.addLegend(100, 10, 510, 20, "right");
    barChart.width = 600;
    barChart.height = 400;
    barChart.draw();
}
```